# Not able to display hash on rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

**How to display value from Hash onto page**

I have a hash in my User model class

```
GENDERS = {'1' => 'Male', '2' => 'Female', '3' => 'Secret'}
```

And i store the key for every user.
So when user read their info, i want to display corresponding value regarding to the key
So i am doing like this:

```
<td><%= User::GENDERS[@user.gender] %></td>
```

But i cannot see anything display.

if i do the following,i do see the right key display

```
<td><%= @user.gender %></td>
```

So, what is the right way to display a value from a hash onto page programatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the gender field a string or an integer? If it's an integer, you'll need to change the hash to:

```
GENDERS = {1 => 'Male', 2 => 'Female', 3 => 'Secret'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just note that this is not particularly good style. You should rather write a method within `User.rb`:

```
GENDERS = {1 => 'Male', 2 => 'Female', 3 => 'Secret'}

def gender_name
  GENDERS[gender]
end
```

and then in your view call:

```
<td><%= @user.gender_name %></td>
```

That way you will not expose that much of your model in the views and keep everything transparent. It will also allow you to modify the display later if you want, without having to change the views.

Answer (score 0):

use model's accessor that get corresponded to a constant gender